# object-fit and hover in firefox

Tags: css, image, object, opacity, cover

I want to fit an image with his parent dimensions. I don't want to use the image as background because is not clearly for google whether the image is using for styling or for content propose.

Anyway, i found object-fit and seems to be what I need.

My big problem now is that object-fit and hover doesn't work together as I expected.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/53/file-385992610-jpg/html-code.jpg" />
</div>

<style>
div{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  opacity:0.5;
}

div img:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

And here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jx0ntkmy/

Hovering several times you will see a distortion of image. I have tested in firefox and chrome. In chrome there is no problem, but in firefox it is.

Comment: can't see any issue in FF

Comment: Hover In and out several times. I have firefox 39.

Comment: I did, using FF45.0.2

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much! I downloaded 45.0.2 and that's ok now. This means that my problem was an old bug of firefox...